# How to download external file using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to download an apk file on a button click using phonegap. Why does this code not work? Nothing happens when I click Download. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<script charset="utf-8" src = "jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src = "cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>

<script>
function foo()
{
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
    "http://samplewebsite.com/example.apk",
    "file:///sdcard/example.apk",
    function(entry) {
    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }    
);
}


</script>

</head>


<body>

<button onclick="foo()">Download</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);
    var filePath= "/sdcard/directory/file.extension";
    fileTransfer.download(uri,filePath,
    function(entry) {
        //success 
    },
    function(error) {
        //failed
    }
    );
```

This worked for me

Comment: is there any way to know when download finished

Comment: @AshishNautiyal 3rd argument is callback function

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. 
This seems stupid but have you tried to use alert() instead of console.log() in the callbacks?

If you are sure the callback code is not invoked try to run just the app created by the phonegap' create script and check that the device is ready before doing other tests.

just my 2c